# To have a distribution for integer

Tags: random, gis, anylogic

I have a parameter that says default value 120 in the main that is linked to the initial number of agents for a particular agent. Now if I wanted that parameter to provide random numbers between 115 to 125 I tried using some distribution but it didn't work.
[image: Before]
[image: after]

Comment: "I tried using some distribution but it didn't work" is extremely vague. What distribution? How did you try it? What does "it didn't work" mean?

Comment: What did you try? What result? What do you expected? Please help us to help you better. And which kind of distribution are you looking? Uniform? -- edit. I saw, you want a triangular distribution (so please write in the question). You have also tag "gis" but it is generic. Which software are you using? Did you check the meaning of the parameter of TRIANGULAR?

Comment: I wanted a triangular distribution but ill make sure to write that the next time. I am using AnyLogic(tagged) and GIS in that software. Artem P. has answered my question and it worked. But ill make sure to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The error shown in the screenshot refers to type mismatch. `triangular()` returns a `double` but the parameter is of type `int`. This particular error can be fixed by changing the code to `(int)triangular(2,5)`.

Admittingly, it would be good to understand what the purpose of this is in order to provide a more useful method as this approach will generate a sample value between 2 and 5 only at model start.